# Does magnetic field depend on $z$ inside a toroidal coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Imagine a circular toroid coiled with a wire through which some current $I$ is flowing. Everywhere it is stated that the magnetic field inside this toroid can be calculated as $$\vec{B} = \mu \frac{NI}{2\pi r} \ \hat{\phi}$$

where $\mu$ is the magnetic permeability of the toroid, $N$ the number of loops the coil presents, $r$ the distance to the center of the toroid and $\hat{\phi}$ the typical versor in cylindrical coordinates.

My cuestion is: **why doesn't the magnetic field depend on $z$, the vertical position?**

As I see it, there is no symmetry in $z$ that allows us to automatically discard this coordinate. Namely,  as we move radially (varying $r$), the field changes because the situation differs from one radius to another: we get closer to (or further away from) the wires, and that makes the field vary. If we moved along the $z$ direction, the case would be analogous. If we center the coordinate system such that the plane $z=0$ slices the toroid in two halves, we can see that at $z=0$ the current has just a component in the $\hat{z}$ direction, but if we analyze this for any other value of $z$ the current acquires other components as well. So I don't see why the magnetic field would not depend on $z$.

Does it depend on $z$ or not? If yes, how can one then calculate the actual magnetic field (the technique that would be used if the section was squared would no longer apply, I guess)?

Comment: The formula that you give for the magnetic field holds only in the $z=0$ plane. It can be obtained easily using Ampère theorem.

Comment: @Christophe That's what I wondered, but there are lots of places where it appears to be valid for any $z$ (like [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/toroid.html) or [here](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Book%3A_Electromagnetics_I_(Ellingson)/07%3A_Magnetostatics/7.07%3A_Magnetic_Field_of_a_Toroidal_Coil), but there are lots of additional places). Is there a way to calculate the actual magnetic field for any $z$?

Comment: I was wrong and I learnt something! The current is symmetric with respect to all the planes containing the $(Oz)$ axis. In any point M, the magnetic field $\vec B(M)$ is therefore perpendicular to the plan containing both M and $(Oz)$, i.e. $\vec B(r,\phi,z)\sim\hat\phi$ for any $z$! The Ampère theorem can by applied to a circular path in any plane z=Cst. When the path is inside the torus, it gives the expression that you give, independently of $z$!

Comment: Related : [Magnetic Induction at the centre of a Toroid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381232/magnetic-induction-at-the-centre-of-a-toroid/416582#416582).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does depend on $z$.

If you think about it, it *must* depend on $z$ to satisfy the boundary conditions when you are close to the wires. You expect a constant value with $z$ only in the middle of the torus, where you can ignore the edge effects.

Ampère's law only reduces to that simple formula if the path element $\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell}$ is parallel to magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$.

But anyway, I did the maths.

I have 20 current loops azimuthally distributed, so that the magnetic field magnitude in the $xy$ plance, at $z=0$, looks like this:

[image]

The radius of each loop is $3$, and the torus is "centred" at $10$, so that its inner and outer radii are $7$ and $13$.

Now let's look at the three components of the magnetic field, at $x=10, y=0$:

[image]

And then I plotted the only $B_{\phi}$, still at $y=0$ but now varying $x$:
[image]

You can see that actually the $B_\phi$ value is quite constant with $x$ provided that you are not too close to the edge (this time in the $x$ direction). This is wrong though, as you’d expect the field to go down $\propto 1/r$ — I suspect this is an artifact of a finite number of current loops.

**Conclusion**

- Away from the edges, the field is essentially independent of $z$.
- The field is *always* in the azimuthal $\phi$ direction, as suggested by @Christophe in the comment).