# Magnetic field in a toroid

Tags: magnetic-fields, vector-fields

How does the magnetic field becomes 0 outside a toroid? Also how can we explain it with magnetic field lines?

Comment: Draw a toroid with a tightly wound coil around it. Now apply Ampere's law. Why would you think that there is non-negligible field *outside* the toroid?

Comment: @hyportnex What are you saying, is there field present outside a toroid?

Comment: You have to consider it as an ideal toroid.

Comment: Related : (1) [Does magnetic field depend on z inside a toroidal coil?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/561849/does-magnetic-field-depend-on-z-inside-a-toroidal-coil#comment1268857_561849),(2) [Magnetic Induction at the centre of a Toroid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381232/magnetic-induction-at-the-centre-of-a-toroid/416582#416582).

Comment: I ask, have you seen the reasoning for why the magnetic field is considered negligible outside a solenoid? If so you can apply the same reasoning to a toroidal coil.

Comment: @Triatticus For that the radius of the toroid must be very less than its length.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/328655/does-a-dc-supplied-superconductive-coil-gives-off-radiation

Comment: @HarrisonWells what I mean is in essence  exactly what hyportnex mentioned, it's the same proof and doesn't matter the specific dimensions of the torus as you're just interested in a small segment of it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You might have heard of amperes circuit law which states that integral of B.dl is equal to current enclosed in the loop and we see that outside a toroid we can't find any current enclosed so magnetic field is 0

Comment: Nope, you can't say that for sure! The looped line integral is 0 (and not the magnetic field). Hence, it can't be said that magnetic field is 0 as the integral is looped.

Comment: You may want to describe where you are putting your chosen loop and the symmetry involved.